# Tap and Drag events not working on objects inside a clipped layer

Tags: kineticjs

I have a layer->group->shape. The group and shape are both draggable and I have also applied a tap event on the shape.

I can drag around the group but the touch events don't work on the shape if I clip the layer. The mouse events work fine on the shape, everything works on the PC browser, even with the clipped layer. What could be wrong here?

Update: This happens only on iPad retina. It works on iPad Non-Retina.

Comment: did you check this issue on github https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/611 ?

Comment: Kinetic.pixelRatio = 1; That fixed it! Thanks Sahar for solving my problem!